# Can't access data within svg/xml path element with jquery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I'm looking at this map:

http://kartograph.org/showcase/usa-projection/usa.svg

This selector

```
$('svg g path')
```

Gives me this in the console

```
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M625,251L623,248L621,246L594,250L578,251L568,252L551,252L551,253L552,254L555,260L556,260L558,263L558,265L559,265L561,267L567,269L567,271L566,271L564,276L567,279L569,283L570,284L573,284L573,285L575,325L576,334L576,345L590,344L601,344L645,340L659,338L660,340L661,340L661,342L656,350L669,348L669,346L671,345L668,343L671,341L670,341L671,340L671,338L671,336L670,336L672,335L672,336L672,336L673,336L673,336L673,333L676,334L677,332L676,330L677,325L677,324L676,325L672,324L672,322L669,318L670,317L668,309L665,308L665,307L661,305L660,306L659,304L654,301L651,299L651,296L652,291L653,289L653,287L654,284L647,282L646,284L644,283L643,280L643,279L642,276L640,274L636,271L633,269L630,266L629,264L628,263L628,262L627,259L626,252L627,251L625,251Z " data-key="MO" data-label="Missouri"/>
```

I'd like to access just the data-key attribute. I've tried

```
$('svg g path').data("key")

$('svg g path').attr("data-key")

$('svg g path[data-key]') (this one returns the whole path node)

$('svg g path').find('data-key')
```

I'm out of ideas and this should be easy. Please help.

Comment: When you say you're looking at that map, do you mean you have opened that URL in your browser and are using the console while viewing that image? If so, then jQuery isn't being loaded - `$` represents something different. You can verify this by checking `$ instanceof jQuery`, or even replacing the `$()` call with `jQuery()` and you'll get an error saying jQuery isn't defined.

Comment: Hmm, so would one of these methods work if I were to host the image myself with jquery loaded?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use either of the first two. The `[data-key]` in the third just asks jQuery to return a `path` element only if it has that attribute - which it does - and `.find()` looks for an *element* called `data-key`, rather than an attribute.

Comment: You have to embed the SVG within your page. Meaning, take the entire code (but remove the `<?xml...?>` and the DOCTYPE) and put it within an HTML file (say, within a `<div>`) that uses jQuery. So it would basically look like `<div><svg>...</svg></div>`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/PHycv/ (it seems to be working)

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned, the `$` variable in this case is not jQuery.

Having said that, it *does* function as a selector, which is why you got the element back when you called `$('svg g path')`. You can use the selector, along with regular DOM methods (vanilla JavaScript) to get at the information you want.

Try this:

```
$('svg g path').attributes['data-key'].value
```